# Node.js express RESTful API failed to render html pages in ie9

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, express

I used express to build RESTful API:

```
app.get("/test/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("test.html");
});
```

in other browsers it works,
but in ie<10,
the URL turns from http://ip:3100/test/ 
to http://ip:3100/#/test/
with an additional hash tag and failed to render the html page.

How to fix this problem?
thanks a lot.